# How to use Application Constants in applescript droplet

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create applescript for cueing software "*QLab*".
I want to get QLab's constants [***continue mode***] within Applescript droplet.

```
tell application "QLab" to tell front workspace

    set AllCueList to every cue list
    set AllCue to cue of item 1 of AllCueList
    set theMode to continue mode of item 1 of AllCue as string
    
    display dialog theMode

end tell
```

Run by "script editor.app" , that's program run successfully and get correct constant in string.

But when save as "droplet" or "application" format and running, get Double Angle `«constant ****»`.

I need any declaration or pre-processing ?
I want to get constant defined by that application.

Comment: That’s normal. AppleScript loads an app’s terminology only when compiling a script, not when running it, so what you see is the raw underlying four-char codes to which the human-readable keywords were compiled. While it is possible to “trick” an applet into loading the app’s dictionary using a `run script` command, making its human-readable terms available at run-time, Robert’s solution is simple and practical and how I would normally do it as well.

Comment: @foo
Thanks you!
I found out why get Double Angle « » and understand process that applescript loads app's terminology.

Comment: @foo I'd like to know that "trick". I tried the way using `run script` command, however I don't find it. Could you tell me that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "QLab" to tell front workspace
    
    set AllCueList to every cue list
    set AllCue to cue of item 1 of AllCueList
    set theMode to continue mode of item 1 of AllCue
    
    if theMode is do_not_continue then
        set theMode to "do_not_continue"
    else if theMode is auto_continue then
        set theMode to "auto_continue"
    else
        set theMode to "auto_follow"
    end if
    
    display dialog theMode
    
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks you!
I succeeded to get correct constant as strings, using your code to my script.